# Question on a cone of an inverse system.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $(X_i,f_{ij})$ be an inverse system of objects and morphisms (say over $\mathbb{N}$) in a category $C$ and let $X$ in $C$ together with morphisms $\pi_i:X\rightarrow X_i$ be the [inverse limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit)  of $(X_i,f_{ij})$. Now, let $(Y, \gamma_i)$ be the pair consisting of $Y$ an object in $C$ together with morphisms $\gamma_i$ s.t. $\gamma_i=f_{ij}\circ\gamma_j$ for all $i \leq j$. Then, by definition of the inverse limit, there exists a unique morphism $u:Y\rightarrow X$ s.t. $\gamma_i = \pi_i \circ u$ for all $i$.

**Question**: is $u$ always injective? Suppose $x \in ker(u)$ and that $x \neq 0$. Then since $\pi_i$ is a morphism and since $\gamma_i = \pi_i \circ u$ we must have that $\pi_i(x)=0$ for all $i$. But is that only possible if $x=0$, giving me a contradiction?

Comment: I take it from talking about $ker(u)$ and $0$ that you intend $C$ to be an abelian category, rather than an arbitrary category?

Comment: You can tackle it on the other end: pick arbitrary non injective $u:Y\to X$ and consider the cone $(\pi_i\circ u)$.

Comment: Why would you expect this? In the category of abelian groups, take the $X_i$ (and hence $X$) to be all the trivial groups with just one element and then take $Y$ to be any non-trivial abelian group.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I don't really know much categorical stuff and initially I meant just the arbitrary category. I quickly looked up abelian categories and I guess $C$ should be abelian if I want to talk about kernels and $0$ in the categorical framework. For now, I am mainly interested in the category of  rings  and so I guess we can assume that $C$ is a category of rings. Thank you for your useful remark.

Comment: @RobArthan Clearly I haven't thought about this enough in greater generality. Thanks for a nice counter example!

Comment: Thank for the hint @Berci. Unfortunately, I can't quite see how I could use it.

Comment: Berci is saying that every map $f: Y \rightarrow X$ has the universal property w.r.t the cone $(\pi_i \circ f)$. Thus since every map probably isn't injective (monomorphism) in the category you are working with you can just choose an $f: Y \rightarrow X$ which isn't injective as a counter example.